# RegEx Pattern Help to Split String

Tags: regex, split, managed-c++

I am having a terrible time trying to get a regular expression defined to split a string that will look like the following . . .

```
SQL12345,54321SQL    

XXXXX,XXXXX

Where X = [0-9A-Za-z] and can be repeated one or more times on each side of the delimeter (,).
```

The RegEx Pattern I've come up with is . . .

```
"([0-9A-Za-z]+)(,)([0-9A-Za-z]+)"
```

I only ever want one group on each side of the delimeter.  I seem to be getting results that look like . . .

```
myStrArr[0] = ""
myStrArr[1] = "SQL12345"
myStrArr[2] = ","
myStrArr[3] = "54321SQL"
myStrArr[4] = ""
```

So, why am I getting the line beginning and line end (array elements 0 and 4).  And, how can I fix my regex pattern so I don't get these returned?

THANK YOU!

Comment: What language? And why not use a simple String Split on the comma for this? Regex here seems like overkill.

Comment: +1 to Paul's answer. Regex seems to be needless here. If you are only interested in the strings and not the patterns, then a string split should solve the purpose. And based on your array structure, I am guessing you are using python. Is that so?

Comment: This is Managed C++ in VS2008.  A Win Form app.

Comment: You could have clued us in with some semicolons. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

user364939's code won't compile. Try this:

```
    System.String  originalString = "SQL12345,54321SQL";
    System.String[] splitArray = originalString.Split(',');

    System.Console.WriteLine(splitArray[0]);
    System.Console.WriteLine(splitArray[1]);
```

Caveat: I tested this with C# in Snippet Compiler but made the .NET references verbose hoping that it will translate nicely to managed C++.

Here's a managed C++ version:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    String^ p = "SQL12345,54321SQL";
    array<String^>^ a = p->Split(',');

    Console::WriteLine(a[0]);
    Console::WriteLine(a[1]);

    Console::ReadLine();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404783/regex-pattern-help-to-split-string/4404983#4404983) could be a better solution if you don't want to use a regular expression. If you do, though, try this one:

```
([^,]+),([^,]+)
```

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the dude above. Unless you care about other weird characters like | etc. Then you'd want to split on anything that is not [0-9A-Za-z].

```
   String myString = "SQL12345,54321SQL";
   String[] array = myString .split(",");
```

Comment: -1 split won't compile due to casing. No biggie. But the Split method does not accept a single string parameter. You have to pass in a char.